# Most powerful size-$\alpha$ test for $f(x|\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$ where $0 < x < 1$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

The question is

Let $\theta_0 < \theta_1$, show that the most powerful size-$\alpha$ test of $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs. $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ rejects for small values of $T$.

I'm having issues because I can't seem to show that it rejects for small values.  I keep getting that it would reject for large values of $T$.

So far, I have:
$\Lambda = \frac{\prod\theta_0x_i^{\theta_0-1}}{\prod\theta_1x_i^{\theta_1-1}}=\frac{\theta_0^n(\prod x_i)^{\theta_0-1}}{\theta_1^n(\prod x_i)^{\theta_1-1}}=\frac{\theta_0^n}{\theta_1^n}(\prod x_i)^{\theta_0-\theta_1}$

Here is where I'm getting a bit lost; either I'm misinterpreting, or my algebra is wrong, but I get that because $\theta_0<\theta_1$, $\frac{\theta_0^n}{\theta_1^n}<1$ and $\Lambda$ will decrease as $\prod x_i$ increases because $\theta_0-\theta_1<0$.

Any guidance is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748720/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Neyman Pearson Lemma allows you to find the MP test at level $\alpha$ in the following way:

> Reject $H_0$ if $$\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta_1}(X_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta_0}(X_i)}\geq K$$ for some $K>0$.

Then you get the likelihood ratio as,$$\left(\dfrac{\theta_1}{\theta_0}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^nX_i^{\theta_1-\theta_0}\geq K$$

Now you are given $\theta_1>\theta_0$. So in particular, taking log on both sides, and noting that $\theta_1/\theta_0$ and $\theta_1-\theta_0$ are afterall  constants, you essentially get that for some $K^*$ you have $$\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\geq K^*$$.

Essentially, you have then by taking exponential function on both sides,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\geq C$$ for some $C\geq0$.

So rejection indeed occurs at large values of your sufficient statistic $T=\prod_i X_i$.

Comment: So, my logic was correct and this distribution rejects for large values of T?  Thanks!